# Associating A User Model with an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design

So in my rails app, I'm creating a table of users, and in that table I have columns such as "email, password, and image". I want to add a concrete list of nationalities that a user can be associated with.

So, I created a user model:
rails g model User email password image:string

Now I want an array of nationalities... so instead of creating an array, I created a separate model for nationalities and want to associate it to my users. Assuming one can have multiple nationalities, I set it up like this:

rails g model Nationality name:string

So in user.rb I wrote:
has_many :nationalities

and in nationality.rb I wrote:
belongs_to :user

When a user signs up, I will have a list for them to choose from: American, Canadian, French, etc...
My gut tells me this might be an antipattern since a user won't ever be adding new nationalities to the list... only selecting, but an admin can always add more nationalities.

I'm not getting any errors, but it isn't working in my favor either.
Did I set it up correctly, or should I just use an array and store it in the user's table under a column called "nationalities"?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more a database design question than a Rails question, but I would just have the `Nationality` table serve as the source for a dropdown, but the `User` table would simply have a `nationality` column. I don't see the need for the extra join. Of course, the values in the `nationality` column would come from user selections from that dropdown populated by the `Nationality` table.

Still, your needs may vary. Stick with the join if multiple nationalities are a requirement. As [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: So they wouldn't be connected at all? The dropdown would just be a list, and then whatever the user chooses can be saved in a column in the users table. I think that makes sense! Maybe I was overthinking this one entirely...

Comment: I don't see why they need to be. I feel like otherwise you would have the performance hit of a join with no real benefit.

Comment: Well, actually I was wondering how I would save multiple nationalities in the one nationality column. Am I making them into an array and then saving them to the database? I haven't done that sort of thing in ActiveRecord in a long time so I don't even know if that's possible.

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement. In that case, maybe it is easier to just do it via join then. You can always use caching or indexing if performance becomes an issue. I don't see any reason to waste cycles on something that's relatively trivial compared to your other requirements.

Comment: If you store multiple nationalities values as a serialized array, then you lose the ability to scope your `User` table by `nationality`...that may not be a big deal of course. But if that's a half useful function, you may want to use a many-to-many solution, such as `acts-as-taggable-on`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rails 4? Is Postgresql your DB? If so this combination allows you to store arrays on your user model.

Basically you would modify your migration to look like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name # or whatever attributes you've already defined

      t.string :nationalities, array: true, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Your ActiveRecord model would contain this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nationalities
end
```

This would allow you to create the nationalities list like so:

```
user = User.create(name: 'Bob', nationalities: ['English', 'Australian', 'French'])
```

And obviously extract them like:

```
user.nationalities
=> ['English', 'Australian', 'French']
```

Still, the decision about having an association or a column on the user goes beyond the ease of creating the user with a nationality in a form. The real question is "what role will the nationality play in the app"? Meaning, does the nationality have additional data that would warrant it being it's own model? Or, can it all just sit in the user table?

If the nationality has as much functionality as a user name, than it can stay on the user. However, if nationality can have other attributes on it such as 'date_aquired' than it may have to be it's own model.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4, and am only using SQLite3 by default, but am interested in Postgresql if it makes this sort of thing easier/more natural. I might have to look into that.

Comment: Have you heard about the love affair between Rails 4 and Postgres? :-) http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/a-love-affair-with-postgresql-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 0):

edit: Oops, I didn't address the part of having multiple nationalities. You may want to consider using `acts_as_taggable_on`

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

It nicely handles the many-to-many behavior of tagging with some built in conveniences.

I think it's fine to use some kind of global array (in a namespace) for Nationalities for now, because as you note correctly, the kind of Nationalities will not change.

However, I think things will be a little more complicated than a straight-up Array...You say you will give choices such as `American, Canadian, French`...and that's fine, but what if the context of a view calls for using `U.S., Canada, France` instead? Then your Array becomes a Hash...I doubt it'll get complicated enough to require a full fledged Rails model. A simple Hash should cover most of those use cases.

I've found it helpful in such situations to create a separate Class or Module. For example, with Gender, it's most definitely not worth creating a separate DB table...and yet, even if all I store in a user's `gender` column is "M", "F", "O" (for other, or maybe not specified), I'll create a `Gender` module that can handle that domain logic:

```
class Gender

   # better to make this private so that
   # only the factory constructor is exposed 
   def initialize(g)
     @g = g 
   end 

   def to_s  # and equivalent methods for serializing Gender into a M/F for database 
     return @g.to_s
   end 

   def pronoun 
     case @g
     when :M
       'he' 
     when :F
       'she'
     else
       'they'
   end 

end

def Gender(str) 
    case str
    when /^(?:m|male|man|boy)$/i
     Gender.new(:M)
    when /^(?:f|female|woman|girl)$/i
     Gender.new(:F)
    else 
     Gender.new(:O)
    end 
end
```